# Android - How to delete 2 point in bottom of tabhost

Tags: android

How to delete 2 point in bottom of tabhost
Please see below image to get more detail.
Thanks so much.

[image]

This is XML, I'm using default tabhost and i don't know why they appear

```
<FrameLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">
            <TabHost android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">        

                    <FrameLayout
                        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="-4dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" >

                    </FrameLayout>

                    <TabWidget
                        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                        style="@color/white"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </TabHost>
        </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to post the XML/Code you used to create this.

Comment: have you tried placing the TabWidget inside the framelayout with the ID: tabcontent?

Comment: you need to have a opening tag for the linear layout. also remove the layout_weight attribute as it isn't necessary and you are using it incorrectly. depending on the orientation of the linear_layout then the children inside will either have 0dp of height or width.